# Phonegap IOS Build no icons

Tags: ios, cordova, gulp, icons, phonegap-build

I'm building an app. That refuses to display the icons. When I launch it in Gulp and run my ripple it does not display the icon. Nor does it display the icon when I upload it to the Phonagap build.

FOr my COnfig.XML I have:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget id="be.aarixa.neglectx" version="2.2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" android-versionCode="" windows-packageVersion="2.2.0.1">
  <name>NeglectXMobile</name>
  <description>
       Neglect-X Mobile
    </description>
  <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
    <string>010</string>
  </gap:config-file>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
       aariXa
    </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
  </feature>
  <preference name="KeepRunning" value="True" />
  <preference name="ShowTitle" value="True" />
  <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="True" />
  <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="True" />
   <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.1.0" />
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~1.0.8" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" version="1.5.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" version="4.1.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" version="2.1.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" version="2.1.1" />

  <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" version="1.2.1"/>

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-keyboard" version="1.1.4" src="https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard" />
  <preference name="WindowsStoreDisplayName" value="NeglectXMobile" />
  <vs:platformSpecificValues xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps">
    <vs:platformSpecificWidget platformName="windows" id="neglectx">
      <vs:appxPackageIsForStore>False</vs:appxPackageIsForStore>
      <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.1.0" />
      <preference name="windows-appx-target" value="uap" />
      <vs:packageOutputPath>D:\Dev\A\neglectx_mobile_2_2\NeglectX_Mobile\AppPackages\</vs:packageOutputPath>
    </vs:platformSpecificWidget>
  </vs:platformSpecificValues>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" version="1.0.0" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm"/>
   <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0"/>
   <!-- iPhone 6 / 6+ -->
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />

<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />

<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />

<!-- Settings Icon -->
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />

<!-- Spotlight Icon -->
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
</widget>
```

A view of my project resources:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, GULP did not add the resource directory so I had to add it to the zip and then upload it to phonegap build.

To make sure: here is my latest config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget id="be.aarixa.neglectx" version="2.2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" android-versionCode="" windows-packageVersion="2.2.0.1">
  <name>NeglectXMobile</name>
  <description>
       Neglect-X Mobile
    </description>
  <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
    <string>010</string>
  </gap:config-file>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
       aariXa
    </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
  </feature>
  <preference name="KeepRunning" value="True" />
  <preference name="ShowTitle" value="True" />
  <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="True" />
  <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="True" />
   <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.1.0" />
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~1.0.8" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" version="1.5.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" version="4.1.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" version="2.1.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" version="2.1.1" />

  <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" version="1.2.1"/>

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-keyboard" version="1.1.4" src="https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard" />
  <preference name="WindowsStoreDisplayName" value="NeglectXMobile" />
  <vs:platformSpecificValues xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps">
    <vs:platformSpecificWidget platformName="windows" id="neglectx">
      <vs:appxPackageIsForStore>False</vs:appxPackageIsForStore>
      <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.1.0" />
      <preference name="windows-appx-target" value="uap" />
      <vs:packageOutputPath>D:\Dev\A\neglectx_mobile_2_2\NeglectX_Mobile\AppPackages\</vs:packageOutputPath>
    </vs:platformSpecificWidget>
  </vs:platformSpecificValues>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" version="1.0.0" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm"/>
   <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0"/>

  <icon src="resources/icon.png"/>

<!-- iPhone 6 / 6+ -->
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />

<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />

<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />

<!-- Settings Icon -->
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />

<!-- Spotlight Icon -->
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />

</widget>
```